# React on HTTP response before response is done?

Tags: ruby, http

Is it possible with any Ruby library to start doing something when a pattern is matched from a HTTP response, before the HTTP session is finished/closed and before the entire result is fetched from the server?

Pseudo code:

```
http.get 'http://example.org/foo.json' do |response|
  run_this_function if /\"field\":\"data\"/ =~ response.body_str
end
```

I want something similar to [odoe.js](https://github.com/jimhigson/oboe.js), but in Ruby.

Comment: Are you running on rails or just ruby?

Comment: Just ruby. I am writing a http client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally Net::HTTP will pull the entire body into memory, but you can change that behavior into streaming. From [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#label-Streaming+Response+Bodies):

> Streaming Response Bodies¶ ↑
>
> By default Net::HTTP reads an entire response into memory. If you are handling large files or wish to implement a progress bar you can instead stream the body directly to an IO.

```
uri = URI('http://example.com/large_file')

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri

  http.request request do |response|
    open 'large_file', 'w' do |io|
      response.read_body do |chunk|
        io.write chunk
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You'll want your code to camp out in the [`read_body`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPResponse.html#method-i-read_body) block. See the documentation for [`read_body`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPResponse.html#method-i-read_body) as there is additional information you should be aware of, but basically it says:

> If a block is given, the body is passed to the block, and the body is provided in fragments, as it is read in from the socket.